# MIPS (arrays and loops)

Tags: arrays, loops, mips

so i am working on a project which asks the user for numbers (integers) and than rearranges them in ascending order and prints them out.
now i am stuck because i want to also print them in descending order but in a separate array with the same numbers. can anyone help me out?
this is my code so far for ascending numbers:
(btw the comments are just for my guiding)

```
.data 
array1: .space 100
array2: .space 100
array3: .space 100

msg1: .asciiz "Enter at least 4 integers: Enter the number 500 to exit \n"
msg2:  .asciiz "Numbers you entered are: \n"
msg3: .asciiz "The numbers you entered in ascending order are: \n"
commas: .asciiz ","
msg4: .asciiz "The numbers you entered in descending order are: \n"

.text
.globl main
main:
la $a1, array1  #load pointer to array1
la $a2, array2  ##load pointer to array2
la $a3, array3  #load pointer to array3
li $t1, 500                   # once 500 is entered it will exit the input and produce an output
li $t0, 0


loopset:

la $a0, msg1    #loads msg1 text into $a
li $v0, 4        #loads 4 into $v0 (prints string) 
syscall         
li $v0, 5           #loads 5 into $v0 (read interger)
syscall        
beq $v0,$t1,swap
addi $t0,$t0,4      #add 4 to $t0, save to $t0
sw $v0, ($a1)       #stores input into array
addi $a1, $a1,4     #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1
j loopset


swap:

la $t4, array1      #loads array1 to $t4
la $t1, array1      #loads array1 to $t1
addi $t1, $t1, 4    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1 
la $t8, array1      #loads array to $t8
add $t8,$t0,$t8     #add $t8 to $t0, save to $t8
la $t9,array1   #loads array1 to $t9 
add $t9, $t0, $t9   #add $t9 to $t0, save to $t9
addi $t9, $t9, -4   #subtracts 4 from $t9, save to $t9

loop1:

lw $t2, ($t4)       #load input into $t2
lw $t3, ($t1)       #load input into $t3
blt $t2, $t3, loop2     #if $t2 > $t3, go to loop2
sw $t3, ($t4)       #store $t3 in $t4
sw $t2, ($t1)       #store $t2 in $t1

loop2:

addi $t1, $t1, 4        #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
blt $t1, $t8, loop1     #if $t1< $t8, go to loop1
addi $t4, $t4, 4        #add 4 to $t4, save to $t4
move $t1, $t4
addi $t1, $t1, 4        #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
blt $t4, $t9, loop1     #if $t4 < $t9, to go loop1


print:

la $a1, array1          #loads array to $a1
la $a0, msg3    #loads msg3 to $a0
li $v0, 4
syscall
la $a0, array1      #loads array1 to $a0
li $v0, 4           #loads 4 into #v0
syscall

loop3:

blez $t0, EXIT       #if $t0 <= 0, go to EXIT
li $v0, 1           #loads 1 into $v0
lw $a0, 0($a1)      #load an input into $a0
syscall
la $a0, commas      #loads commas into $a0
li $v0, 4           #loads 4 into $v0
syscall
addi $a1, $a1, 4    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1
addi $t0, $t0, -4   #subtracts 4 from #t0, save to $t0
j loop3


EXIT:
li $v0,10              #exit 
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing out all of the blt (branch less than) to bgt (branch greater than) and assuming your program works like it is supposed to you should get an array in descending order. If you want it in a different array for the descending order you will need to copy your loop1, loop2, loop3, and print and change their names switching out the blt calls for bgt calls.